# C - Make variable be null in dev C?

Tags: c, null, dev-c++

I want to make variable null in C in dev C.

This code isn't work

```
char a = '5';
a = '';
```

I don't know why this is not work. And I want to make character ***a*** be empty. The error message is
"[Error] empty character constant"

Comment: There's no such thing as an empty character. A `char` is a numeric type, it always has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by empty..

'\0' means the value 0 (NUL).

Comment: @andika_kurniawan `gets()` fills in a string, not a single character.

Comment: @andika_kurniawan: Do yourself a favor: Forget `gets` ever existed.

Comment: Oh, one question again. I want to fill string be empty. For example, char contoh[5] = "ayahz". I want to empty that string and I want to refill that string. How to do that ?

Comment: The 5 you have there is the length of the character array (string). You can store up to 4 characters (and one \0 at the end). So say you have contoh[32] size. You can clear it by contoh[0] = '\0'; You can fill it with strcpy(contoh, "my new string");

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '';
```

is not valid code

for assigning null value:

```
a = '\0';
```